# Start an activity from fragment using bottom navigation bar

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-activity, bottomnavigationview

In my app I have 5 fragments. In order to switch between them i use bottom navigation bar.

Also, i need to open activities from my fragments, but when I open new activity it opens in each of the fragments. (I mean over the fragments, in each case)

How to make the activity open in one case?

My code:

```
 private BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener mOnNavigationItemSelectedListener
        = new BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
        Fragment fragment = null;
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.nav_home:
                fragmentManager.beginTransaction().hide(active).show(fragment1).commit();
                active = fragment1;
                return true;
            case R.id.nav_bookmark:
                fragmentManager.beginTransaction().hide(active).show(fragment2).commit();
                active = fragment2;
                return true;
            case R.id.nav_blog:
                fragmentManager.beginTransaction().hide(active).show(fragment3).commit();
                active = fragment3;
                return true;
            case R.id.nav_notification:
                fragmentManager.beginTransaction().hide(active).show(fragment4).commit();
                active = fragment4;
                return true;
            case R.id.nav_account:
                fragmentManager.beginTransaction().hide(active).show(fragment5).commit();
                active = fragment5;
                return true;
        }
      return false;
    }
};
```

Thanks!

Comment: Could you please add full code?

Answer (score 1):

This is clearly a FragmentManager issue - and not an Activity issue.
Instead `.hide().show()` use `.replace()`.
For reference, see the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/fragment/app/FragmentTransaction#replace(int,%20androidx.fragment.app.Fragment)).

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/21704312)

Comment: @JonathanGagne have you read and understood the question, which is being accurately answered? the other answer, does not answer the question. the issue is obvious and there is nothing more to say about it. this is quality vs. quantity, when comparing the two answers provided. how can you review `Android` questions, while not having any `Android` score? just click `skip`.

Comment: for reference: https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/fragment/app/FragmentTransaction#replace(int,%20androidx.fragment.app.Fragment) ...and this is clearly a `FragmentManager` issue - and not an `Activity` issue.

Answer (score 0):

According to the [Android documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity#ActivityLifecycle), an activity is always placed on top of the current activity stack.

So if you have the `MainActivity` with the `BottomNavigationView` and the fragments, starting a new Activity will open the activity above the `MainActivity` with the `BottomNavigationView`. So it is not possible to open an Activity only in one of the `BottomNavigationView` Fragments.

To achieve the desired behaviour, consider using another `Fragment` instead.

Comment: @MartinZeitler I think he has a point when not using replace together with BottomNavigationView. As far as I understand, with replace in FragmentTransaction, onCreateView of the new Fragment always will be called, which is not so good for app performance. With the code he uses, the Fragment that gets visible won't always call onCreateView. Correct me if I am wrong.